# AArch64 - U-Boot - Boot ELF image with passing multiple arguments (memory addresses) in registers

Tags: arguments, elf, arm64, u-boot, bare-metal

I don't know, if this question is off-topic for Stackoverflow, but before I ask this question in the official U-Boot mailing-list I will ask this on this site.

Have started a bare-metal application (simple Kernel) for the purpose of education. Now I want to implement a simple **initrd** support for loading Kernel modules and load and execute the user application.

Is it possible (maybe with workarounds) with U-Boot to pass multiple arguments in the AArch64 registers, when booting an ELF image?

I know it's maybe possible with the U-Boot [bootm](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxKernelArgs) command. But I haven't currently figured out, how it fully works. The [U-Boot documentation](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/doc/arch/arm64.rst) refers to the [Linux documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/arm64/booting.rst). According to this documentation only register `x0` should be filled with the device-tree-blob address, which I haven't implemented at this time. `x1`, `x2`, `x3` are reserved and should be filled with zeros:

> - Primary CPU general-purpose register settings:
>
>   - x0 = physical address of device tree blob (dtb) in system RAM.
>   - x1 = 0 (reserved for future use)
>   - x2 = 0 (reserved for future use)
>   - x3 = 0 (reserved for future use)

No idea where I can get the other arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

The booti command will add the start and end address to the device tree, e.g.

```
/ {
    chosen {
        linux,initrd-start = <0x82000000>;
        linux,initrd-end = <0x82800000>;
    };
};
```

Please, find the booti command description here:
https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/booti.html

The other possibility is booting via UEFI.

With the efidebug command you can define a boot option, e.g. Boot0000 indicating the location of the kernel and of the initrd. The initrd will be exposed as a EFI_LOAD_FILE2_PROTOCOL when you run 'bootefi bootmgr'.

Or from the EFI stub of your kernel you use the UEFI file protocol to load the initrd.

Building UEFI applications is the easiest using gnu-efi.

Besides the mailing list, there is an #u-boot IRC channel on Freenode.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 3rd option, which is `bootelf` which looking at `cmd/elf.c`

```c
        /*
         * pass address parameter as argv[0] (aka command name),
         * and all remaining args
         */
        rc = do_bootelf_exec((void *)addr, argc, argv)
```